# Win 10 multitasking

Tags: windows-explorer

If I am copying a large number of files from one drive to another using Explorer, and at the same time use Explorer to view another folder, it runs extremely slow as if all the power is going into my original task. As I have an i7 with 16Gb of RAM I'd expect Win 10 to breeze through this!

Explorer also seems to make a meal of tasks generally whereas a utility like Carpenter's Everything instantly displays every file in all four drives. What gives?

Comment: How fast are your disks?
If one disks  IO is maxed out then spare CPU cycles or extra RAM will not help. That disk will be quite busy and any other tasks will competer with its time.  (start, run, resmon, [disk] is a good way to check this on win10).

Comment: Less constuctive: 16Gbit RAM is only 2GByte. (big difference betweeb b abd B).  And 'an i7' does not mean anything. A modern i3 will be lots faster than a 6 year old i7. Just '-something only makes limited sense when comparing specific models or in a limited time frame.

Comment: It won't help that both Windows file copy & NTFS are inherently slow.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to not be your CPU or your RAM - but disk latency.

Your computer is only as fast as its slowest component.  This means that if you have a really fast CPU, tonnes of RAM and a slow disk - for the most part, your computer will only be able to move data as fast as it can read from /write to the disk.

I personally have 20GB RAM and and an i5-4590 which under most circumstances runs like a rocket with windows 10 - however, when I start to thrash the disk, the whole machine slows down.

Evidence of what is happening can be found in Task Manager (Performance Tab):
[image]

You can see that I'm only using ~3% CPU, ~30% RAM, but 100% Disk (to do this, I did a copy/paste of a 20GB file).  While my disk is running at 100% usage - my machine cannot work much faster.

In this scenario, if I wanted to now load an application (Word, Excel, Firefox, media player etc) - these programs files would need to be read from the disk for use - meaning that either the file copies slow down or the application loads need to wait their turn in the disk queue.

Fortunately, Windows is good at multi-tasking - so the 2 jobs will run (slower) side by side - but will result in a performance drop on my PC and this is exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Tetsujiin hit the nail on the head - file copy and NTFS are very slow. But Everything for example, gets around that somehow, so why can't MS? In fact losts of third party programs can copy files miles faster than Windows can. How?